# How to create and send PDF through custom menu item in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created a simple google script that creates and sends a PDF via e-mail to the given address from google document. I have the e-mail address and content set directly in the script, the script is then run via an custom menu item that is located directly in the document.

Does anyone know if it is possible to set up and change the script so that the address, subject and content of the e-mail are not directly in the script, but could they be added using a simple form in the menu item?

Create PDF:

```
function pdf() {

  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();

// Create PDF
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var docblob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');
  docblob.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");

// Send e-mail
  var recipients = "e-mail adress";
  var subject = "Subject";
  var string = "e-mail content";

   var options = {};
        options.name = "name";
        options.replyTo = recipients;
        options.htmlBody = string;
        options.attachments = [docblob];

   MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "Hello", options);

}
```

Menu item:

```
function onOpen(e) {

// Create the menu item in the Google document
   DocumentApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Email')
       .addItem('Send PDF', 'pdf')
       .addToUi();
 }
```

Comment: Why not use dialogs or sidebars - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs ?

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин I've tried it, but it doesn't work for me in google documents. I'm not sure if google only supports this for sheets

Comment: No problem, 2 lines of code: `var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('I am a sidebar.');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);`

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to functions triggered by [Custom menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). You should use [Dialogs and Sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) for that. Check [Client-to-Server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) for how to pass data from client (sidebar/dialog) to server (function `pdf`).

Comment: If you think this workaround would be appropriate for your situation but you need more details on how to proceed, I'd be willing to post an answer regarding this.

Comment: "I'm not sure if google only supports..." - that sound implausible. Every service that has a `getUI()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getui) has a capability to utilize menus, dialogs and sidebars (not to mention editor Add-ons). Please, clarify what does "doesn't work" mean?